# Is inversion logically consistent in neutral geometry?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, noneuclidean-geometry, inversive-geometry

A description of inversion can be found [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inversion.html).

Since the process uses points, circles, lines, extending lines, right angles, and similar triangles, it seems to me that this process could be proven to be consistent in neutral geometry.

If it is helpful, Mohr-Mascheroni proved that any straightedge and compass construction can be performed using only a compass. Therefore, it seems you could perform this process using only the concept of points and distance/circles.

It seems like the largest issue might be the finite nature of reflected straight lines. From what I have seen, the popular approach is that when a straight line is reflected, it becomes a circular arc: a circle with a single point excluded (the origin of the circle of inversion).

Regarding "consistency":

From [this source](http://web.mnstate.edu/peil/geometry/C1AxiomSystem/AxiomaticSystems.htm):
"An axiomatic system is consistent if there is no statement such that both the statement and its negation are axioms or theorems of the axiomatic system."

"In an axiomatic system, an axiom is independent if it is not a theorem that follows from the other axioms."

Since a major aspect of neutral geometry is the exclusion of the parallel postulate, the question is intended to ask if the process of circle inversion (when considered as a statement or theorem) does not force independence from neutral geometry, but instead, establishes logic consistent with it.

Considering these factors, is it sensible to attempt to make or find a proof of consistency?

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent"?  You could ask whether the theory and machinery (i.e., basic theorems) of inversive geometry can be formulated and proved in neutral geometry, but I don't know what that has to do with "consistency".

Comment: consistency appears to be a well-used and understood term in mathematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency

The question is not about the theory of inversive geometry, it is merely related to inversive geometry, since inversive geometry uses circle inversion.

Some tools or processes may be consistent in some systems, but inconsistent in others. I am asking about circle inversion in neutral geometry.

Comment: Inverses exist in standard Euclidean geometry, which is a model of neutral geometry. So the existence of inverses is certainly consistent with the axioms of neutral geometry, but for boring reasons. I've tried to answer the question I think you meant to ask (namely, whether those axioms are strong enough to give a well-defined notion of inversion).

Comment: Ah. yes. I expected that I had expressed something poorly, and I see that using "consistency" causes a confusion. I'm not sure if that is the question I meant to ask, but your answer is in the direction I was looking for. If I am more sure about how to word things better, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

It is a theorem of neutral geometry that any point interior to a circle has at most one inverse with respect to that circle. But you need the parallel postulate to show that this inverse actually exists.

To see this, suppose $P'$ is a point inside a circle centered at $O$ with $P' \ne O$, and you want to construct the inverse $P$ of $P'$. Explicitly, the construction runs as follows:

1. Construct the line $OP'$.
2. Draw a perpendicular to that line through $P'$. Let $Q$ be the intersection of this perpendicular with the circle.
3. Construct the line $OQ$.
4. Draw a perpendicular to $OQ$ through $Q$; call this line $\ell$. Let $P$ be the intersection of $\ell$ with the line $OP'$.

In order for this construction to work, we need to know that $\ell$ is not parallel to $OP'$. The Euclidean proof of this fact runs something like:

- Draw a perpendicular line $m$ to $P'Q$ through $Q$. Then $m$ is parallel to $OP'$, because both $m$ and $OP'$ are perpendicular to $P'Q$.
- Because $P'$ and $O$ are distinct points, $m$ and $\ell$ are distinct lines.
- Because $m \ne \ell$ and $m$ and $\ell$ both pass through the point $Q$, it follows by the uniqueness of parallels that $\ell$ is not parallel to $OP'$.

But the last step is an application of the parallel postulate, so this is not valid neutrally. Indeed, the construction can fail in the hyperbolic plane.

For an explicit example of this in the Poincaré disk model, let $O=(0,0)$ and $P'=\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)$, and take the circle $x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{2}$ centered at $O$. The hyperbolic line $OP'$ is the a segment of the $x$-axis; the perpendicular to that line through $P'$ is a segment of the circle $x^2-\frac{5}{2}x+y^2+1=0$. This perpendicular intersects the given circle $x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{2}$ when $x=\frac{3}{5}$, so we can take $Q=\left(\frac{3}{5},\sqrt{\frac{7}{50}}\right)$. But then the hyperbolic line $\ell$ ends up being a segment of the circle $\frac{6}{5}x+\frac{\sqrt{14}}{5}y=\frac{2}{3}(x^2+y^2+1)$. This circle does not intersect the $x$-axis, so the line $\ell$ does not intersect the line $OP'$.

That is, points need not have inverses. On the other hand, the point $P$ is defined as an intersection of two lines, which is unique whenever it exists. And the first three steps in the construction are all legitimate in neutral geometry. So this construction always produces at most one point, which completes the proof of the claim in my first paragraph.

Comment: but the construction also 'fails' in the euclidean plane as well, doesn't it? when P' is O, step 2 is no longer valid in the euclidean plane, right? and when P' is a point on the circle, it is also a different case. Aren't those cases similar to the hyperbolic non-intersection?

I see that you invoked the parallel postulate, but a major portion of the question is whether it's possible without using the parallel postulate. I'm not expert, but couldn't you construct similar triangles and use those in cases where there is a reflection?

Comment: 1) In the Euclidean plane, there is no inverse when $P'=O$, but there is an inverse for any other $P'$ inside the circle. This is false hyperbolically, and therefore not provable in neutral geometry.

Comment: 2) It's standard to say that a point on the circle is its own inverse, and this follows from most definitions, but I think it doesn't actually follow from the definition on the Mathworld page. So you're right that the construction fails for certain points in the Euclidean plane, but it fails for a lot more points in the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: re: 1) well it's all well and good to say "any point" but when you exclude a point, it's not "any point" anymore, is it?

Comment: 3) The point is that, if you try to prove the construction works for all interior points except the center, you're naturally led to the parallel postulate. Of course, this doesn't show that there isn't some other clever way to get around the use of the parallel postulate! That's why we go looking in the hyperbolic plane for points where the construction fails: to show that in the absence of the parallel postulate, the existence of $P$ cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: 4) You can't construct similar triangles without the parallel postulate. Similar triangles are not part of neutral geometry.

Comment: re: 3) i think the other points of discussion (1 and 2) show that even in the presence of the parallel postulate, the existence of P can't be guaranteed.

Comment: re: 4) it had seemed odd that someone mentioned a side-angle-side axiom as being neutral. I don't accept your statement as proof, but I do accept it as convincing me XD. further re: 3) so you accept it might be possible to perform the proof for those reflections that do exist without using the parallel postulate?